# Trying to follow along with VSC docs on creating a simple Flask app with Python and cannot get it to run. What Am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

I am following along with this [tutorial on creating a simple flask app with VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) and cannot get app.py to run at all.

The author instructs

"In the Integrated Terminal, run the app by entering python -m flask run, which runs the Flask development server. The development server looks for app.py by default. When you run Flask, you should see output similar to the following:"

```
(.venv) D:\py\\hello_flask>python -m flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I instead am seeing this when i run the same command.

```
python -m flask run
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.
```

[image: This is what my Editor sidebar looks like, in case that's what the issue is.]

I could really use some help here. I feel so stupid for getting so something so simple so wrong and not being able to figure it out.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the directory to the one my app was actually in...duh

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your `app.py` file was placed in the ***.vscode*** folder, which should be in the root directory of your workspace.

##### Solution:

Move the `app.py` to the root directory of the workspace, which is the **hello_flask** folder.

*The ***.vscode*** folder is typically used to place workspace settings or configuration files such as launch.json.*

Comment: Yep, realized it 5 minutes before you commented and answered it below. Thank you though, i'm just jumping back in after over a year and sometimes have some serious "how stupid am i" moments